# Convex Hull of a given value inside an numpy array - python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, convex-hull

For a given array (as the one suggested below) and a given value (here, 0), I would like to count how many 0 can be associate at a same convex hull.

array :

```
1 2 4 5 8 9 7
4 0 0 7 5 6 8
6 5 0 4 3 5 2
1 0 0 5 7 0 6
2 3 5 7 8 9 4
```

For the array suggested, the solution should get : `[5, 1]` because a first "pattern" of five 0 can be identify between the second and fourth line and the second/third columns. A second pattern with only one 0 exist.

Have you any idea about how to get that ? I know how to count the number of 0. Maybe I can do something with the mask option of numpy array ?

Best regards and thank's for your help,

Comment: I think that by "convex hull" you really mean "connected component".  If I understand correctly, the first group of 5 zeros would not be a convex hull because the 5 lies between two elements of the group.

Comment: @Peter yes "connected component" is better for what I want to do.
So yes, the is a pattern of five 0 connected together and a pattern of one 0. How can I quantify these connected component ?

Comment: I found some informations on internet with "connected component" keyword, thank's !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the "connected components" in the array.  Scipy has a convenient `label` function for this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import label

a = np.array([
    [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 7],
    [4, 0, 0, 7, 5, 6, 8],
    [6, 5, 0, 4, 3, 5, 2],
    [1, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0, 6],
    [2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 4],])

labs, n_components = label(a==0)

component_sizes = [np.sum(labs==i) for i in range(1, n_components+1)]

print(component_sizes)
```

Prints `[5, 1]`

Comment: Oh thank you so much.
I was looking on this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737409/finding-connected-components-in-a-pixel-array?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

I was looking how to count the number of component on each labels !

Thank's for your answer, it's working like a charm ! :)