# Subregions of boolean 2d array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Say i have a 2 dimensional boolean array. I would like to get a list of slices/or alike,  where each slice represents the least (in size) subregions of the array contanining True values while its border contains all False.

I could loop for each row and column and store the indices when such condition is met, but i wonder if you know another way or a library that does this efficiently? You can assume that the boundary of the original boolean array is always False/0.

Example 1

[image]

Example 2

[image]

Edit ! Added new examples with the correct solutions. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: not sure you're example is consistent with the logic. Why in the first one of the box bellow should not be included in the bigger one, given that they share a column?

Comment: I made some mistake and i added the same arrays. They represent 2 different examples  and the regions marked in red are the subregions i would like to get the slices for.

Comment: In the first example, shouldn't there be 3 regions? Edit: I suppose it depends on whether you want the regions of maximum size or least size

Comment: The subregion definition is quite confusing, as you can get multiple way to define subregion I think, or you are ok with code produce all possible result

Comment: Nah the definition is is valid and with unique solution. I just dont know where my mind is today and cant even give a the correct solution to my examples.. updating in a second

Comment: @JustANoob Could you update your question with the code that generates the example cases? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding connected components in a pixel-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737409/finding-connected-components-in-a-pixel-array) Isn't that just finding connected components?

Comment: This could be an interesting problem to pose on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's connected component analysis, which has been [asked and answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46738834/11089932). Adapting the accepted answer from there to your needs, a possible solution is quite short:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import label


def analysis(array):
    labeled, _ = label(array, np.ones((3, 3), dtype=np.int))
    for i in np.arange(1, np.max(labeled)+1):
        pixels = np.array(np.where(labeled == i))
        x1 = np.min(pixels[1, :])
        x2 = np.max(pixels[1, :])
        y1 = np.min(pixels[0, :])
        y2 = np.max(pixels[0, :])
        print(str(i) + ' | slice: array[' + str(y1) + ':' + str(y2) + ', ' + str(x1) + ':' + str(x2) + ']')


example1 = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]).astype(bool)

example2 = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]).astype(bool)

for a in [example1, example2]:
    print(a, '\n')
    analysis(a)
    print('\n')
```

That's the output (without the examples):

```
[[...]] 

1 | slice: array[1:2, 3:5]
2 | slice: array[4:6, 6:8]
3 | slice: array[8:8, 2:2]

[[...]] 

1 | slice: array[1:3, 5:8]
2 | slice: array[2:2, 3:3]
3 | slice: array[4:5, 1:1]
4 | slice: array[5:8, 3:6]
5 | slice: array[6:6, 8:8]
6 | slice: array[8:8, 8:8]
```

Hope that helps!

```
------------------
System information
------------------
Python:  3.8.1
SciPy:   1.4.1
------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can approach the problem from a graph perspective, with the coordinates of the ones being the graph elements, 8-way connected - then you just have to find the connected components in the graph. If the data is sparse, this should be quite faster than looping through possible square sizes. This an example of how it could work:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def find_squares(a):
    # Find ones
    ones = [(i, j) for i, row in enumerate(a) for j, val in enumerate(row) if val]
    # Make graph of connected ones
    graph = {a: [] for a in ones}
    for a, b in combinations(ones, 2):
        if abs(a[0] - b[0]) <= 1 and abs(a[1] - b[1]) <= 1:
            graph[a].append(b)
            graph[b].append(a)
    # Find connected components in graph
    components = []
    for a, a_neigh in graph.items():
        if any(a in c for c in components):
            continue
        component = {a, *a_neigh}
        pending = [*a_neigh]
        visited = {a}
        while pending:
            b = pending.pop()
            if b in visited:
                continue
            visited.add(b)
            component.add(b)
            b_neigh = graph[b]
            component.update(b_neigh)
            pending.extend(c for c in b_neigh if c not in visited)
        components.append(component)
    # Find bounds for each component
    bounds = [((min(a[0] for a in c), min(a[1] for a in c)),
               (max(a[0] for a in c), max(a[1] for a in c)))
              for c in components]
    return bounds

a = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
square_bounds = find_squares(a)
print(*square_bounds, sep='\n')
# ((1, 5), (3, 8))
# ((2, 3), (2, 3))
# ((4, 1), (5, 1))
# ((5, 3), (8, 6))
# ((6, 8), (6, 8))
# ((8, 8), (8, 8))
```