# How to check if an object is being block by other objects in an image?

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I have an image input that has a car in the center. and the images have various angles of the car taken. I want to check if the car is fully visible and not being blocked by other objects in the image.

My method is to use object detection to detect a car and other objects in the image. If the IoU of others and a car is more than 80%, I will check that the image is being blocked. But the problem is that there are some situations where the IoU is more than 80% but a car is in front of it, so it can be fully visible. such as the top right and left in the example images below. I want to say that the top row can still be used but the bottom one can't.

Any suggestion for these type of problem?

[image: example images]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using object detection (bounding boxes) alone seems like a poor approach to this problem due to the car potentially occluding detected objects.

You could start by using the bounding boxes just to detect which objects *may* be blocking the car. Then you could perform instance segmentation to get the pixel masks for each of those objects.

This makes it easier to tell which objects occlude the car since their pixels will be intersecting the car. If an object is behind the car, none of the pixels will pass through the car's.

Therefore, after you have the pixel mask of a potentially occluding object, you can [divide the mask into each of its connected components](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46737409/3587606), then see if the bounding box of each connected pixel region has a significant IOU with the bounding box of the car.

You could also use the pixel mask of the car to make your method more accurate. For example, the bounding boxes of the connected pixel regions of an occluded object should rarely enter the pixel mask of the car. On the other hand, the bounding boxes of an object in front of the car will intersect more of the car's pixel mask.