# Find all disjoint subsets of a binray matrix in Pyhton

Tags: python, image-processing, matrix, disjoint-sets

I have a binary matrix, and I want to find all disjoint subsets that exist in this matrix. To clarify the problem, the matrix is a collection of image masks, masks of irregular shapes, and each disjoint subset of 1s representing a separate mask. In other words, if I have a collection of `N` disjoint subsets in a matrix of size `d1xd2`, I want to end up with `N` matrices of size `d1xd2`, each having only one of the disjoint subsets of 1s.
Any help on that is highly appreciated.

Comment: Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I looked into it and thought about implementing it which somebody else kindly did and posted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In image processing, what you are trying to do is also called [Connected Component Labelling (CCL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling). Woodford's suggestion of Flood fill algorithm is one algorithm for performing CCL.

A variation of your question is already answered in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46737409/5675094), which uses the function [`scipy.ndimage.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html#scipy.ndimage.label).
Here's a slight modification of that answer, which should give you exactly what you are looking for:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import label

# Define your matrix here
X = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
], dtype=int)

# How do you define "connected" or "disjointed"? 4-neighbors vs 8-neighbors.
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling
structure = np.ones((3, 3), dtype=int)

# Perform connected component labelling
labeled, ncomponents = label(X, structure)

# Iterate through each labelled blob
for ii in range(1, ncomponents+1):
    output = np.zeros(X.shape)
    output[labeled == ii] = 1

    # Do something to each resulting blob...
    print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works perfectly. This is the type of problem that I enjoy thinking about and normally prefer to solve on my own, but on a tight schedule now and I could suspect people have already come up with solutions to this type of problem. I appreciate the time you spent answering this.