# Speed up flood-fill algorithm to determine inundated areas in a raster image

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, performance, flood-fill

I have a raster image that contains elevations (DEM). I also have some points with specific elevations associated (something like Point(x, y, h) where h is an elevation). I'm trying to, starting from the location of the given point, find all cells CONNECTED in 8 directions so that their elevation is under the elevation of the given point (i.e under h).

As an example, lets say we have the image M and a Point(2,2,2.1). Then, I would like to get the result from matrix MS.

```
M = np.array([
    [2, 6, 6, 6, 6],
    [6, 2, 6, 6, 6],
    [6, 6, 2, 6, 6],
    [6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
    [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
])

MS = np.array([
    [True, False, False, False, False],
    [False, True, False, False, False],
    [False, False, True, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False]
], dtype=bool)
```

For this I implemented a modified version of the flood-fill algorithm:

```
def flood_fill(image, x, y, threshold):
    """
    
    Calculates inundated cells. Cells get inundated if the threshold value is higher
    than the starting point elevation.

    Parameters
    ----------
    image: numpy.ndarray
        array of elevations
    cx : int
        starting coordinate x in pixel coordinates
    cy : int
        starting coordinate y in pixel coordinates
    threshold : float
        threshold elevation.

    Returns
    -------
    filled : numpy.ndarray
        array with boolean values where True means the cells is flooded

    """
    
    filled = np.zeros_like(image, dtype=bool)
    toFill = []
    toFill.append((x,y))
    
    while not len(toFill) == 0:
        (x,y) = toFill.pop()
        
        if x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= image.shape[0] or y >= image.shape[1]:
            continue
        
        if filled[x, y] or image[x, y] > threshold:
            continue
        
        filled[x, y] = 1
        toFill.append((x - 1, y))
        toFill.append((x + 1, y))
        toFill.append((x, y - 1))
        toFill.append((x, y + 1))
        toFill.append((x-1, y - 1))
        toFill.append((x-1, y + 1))
        toFill.append((x+1, y - 1))
        toFill.append((x+1, y + 1))
        
    return filled
```

While it works, is kind of slow for the purposes I'm using it. I also tried with a recursive version, but it explodes when the image is bigger than a few thousand pixels (stack overflow error). Is there a way to make it faster? Or do you know a python library that implements something like this?

As an example for an image of 5000×3000 is the method is taking 15 seconds, which is too much because I have several points.

I uploaded the raster to google drive since it is heavy: [RASTER_DEM](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cl-tU29DB45xrZU_AwxyCC1TrrbOf0C7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: instead of passing the whole image, patchify it and pass one patch of the image at a time. also implement multi-threading to make the whole process faster. and would you mind providing an example image of that size? that way I can give you a solution

Comment: sent you access request

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I edited the post with link to the raster image. It's 80+ Mb. Now it should be okay to access to the file.

Comment: thanks, give me some time. I will get back to you

Comment: This is clearly too big for a CPython script. CPython is an interpreter so it is (very) slow. If you want something fast, you can either use vectorized function doing flood fill ([Scipy should do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737409/finding-connected-components-in-a-pixel-array)), or use a compilation-based solution : using Cython or Numba so to speed this up. The former solution is more Pythonic and certainly simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `flood` function from `skimage`.

This takes around 0.15 seconds per starting point for a 5000x3000 image on my machine, plus reading and writing the file.

```py
from skimage.segmentation import flood
from skimage.io import imread, imsave

# Load your image; doesn't really matter how as long as it's an ndarray.
# Note that this assumes an rgb image.
im = imread("path")

# Some starting point from which to flood
x, y = 351, 137

# Get the elevation by just grabbing the first color channel at `x, y`
elevation = im[y, x, 0]

# Create a boolean ndarray that's True where the image is equal or less than
# the starting point, and False everywhere else. We only look at the first
# color channel because the image is grayscale, hence the "[:,:,0]".
is_lower = im[:,:,0] <= elevation

# Flood fill using skimage.segmentation.flood
mask = flood(is_lower, (y, x))

# Now we can modify all the pixels in the image based
# on the floodfill mask however we want using the mask
im[mask] = elevation

# Save the image
imsave("path", im)
```

Comment: Greeaaat! This works wonderfully well. This makes everything easier.

Comment: @stray_dog if this answer helps you, accept it please. It will give Simon appreciation and others will see that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution that will divide the raster into patches, then do your modified flood-fill on each patch and at the end stitch the image back together. It takes  around 24-30 seconds on my PC.

```
import numpy as np
import concurrent.futures
import rasterio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def process_patch(image_patch, threshold, patch_idx, patch_size, image_size):
    # Assuming flood fill starts at (0, 0) in each patch
    filled_patch = flood_fill(image_patch, 0, 0, threshold)  
    # Calculate the position of the patch in the full image
    patch_x, patch_y = patch_idx
    x_start = patch_x * patch_size
    y_start = patch_y * patch_size
    x_end = min(x_start + patch_size, image_size[0])
    y_end = min(y_start + patch_size, image_size[1])

    return filled_patch[:x_end - x_start, :y_end - y_start], patch_idx

def flood_fill(image, x, y, threshold):
    """
    
    Calculates inundated cells. Cells get inundated if the threshold value is higher
    than the starting point elevation.

    Parameters
    ----------
    image: numpy.ndarray
        array of elevations
    cx : int
        starting coordinate x in pixel coordinates
    cy : int
        starting coordinate y in pixel coordinates
    threshold : float
        threshold elevation.

    Returns
    -------
    filled : numpy.ndarray
        array with boolean values where True means the cells is flooded

    """
    
    filled = np.zeros_like(image, dtype=bool)
    toFill = []
    toFill.append((x,y))
    
    while not len(toFill) == 0:
        (x,y) = toFill.pop()
        
        if x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= image.shape[0] or y >= image.shape[1]:
            continue
        
        if filled[x, y] or image[x, y] > threshold:
            continue
        
        filled[x, y] = 1
        toFill.append((x - 1, y))
        toFill.append((x + 1, y))
        toFill.append((x, y - 1))
        toFill.append((x, y + 1))
        toFill.append((x-1, y - 1))
        toFill.append((x-1, y + 1))
        toFill.append((x+1, y - 1))
        toFill.append((x+1, y + 1))
        
    return filled

# Define image parameters
image_path = 'clipped_dem_romboutswervepolder.tif'

# choose your desired threshold
threshold_value = 1.05

# Adjust based on memory constraints
patch_size = 1024  

# Read the dem
with rasterio.open(image_path) as dataset:
    tif_array = dataset.read(1)
    image_size = tif_array.shape
    print("loaded raster-image size: ", image_size)
print("Unique values in input array:", np.unique(tif_array))

# Create an output array
output_array = np.zeros_like(tif_array, dtype=bool)


start = time.time()
# Process patches using ProcessPoolExecutor
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = []

    num_patches_x = image_size[0] // patch_size + 1
    num_patches_y = image_size[1] // patch_size + 1

    for px in range(num_patches_x):
        for py in range(num_patches_y):
            patch = tif_array[px * patch_size:(px + 1) * patch_size, py * patch_size:(py + 1) * patch_size]
            futures.append(executor.submit(process_patch, patch, threshold_value, (px, py), patch_size, image_size))

    # Retrieve results and place them in the output array
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        filled_patch, patch_idx = future.result()
        patch_x, patch_y = patch_idx
        x_start = patch_x * patch_size
        y_start = patch_y * patch_size
        x_end = min(x_start + patch_size, image_size[0])
        y_end = min(y_start + patch_size, image_size[1])
        output_array[x_start:x_end, y_start:y_end] = filled_patch
        
print("time taken: ", time.time() - start)

# Visualize the result
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))

axs[0].imshow(tif_array, cmap='gray')
axs[0].set_title('Input Data')

axs[1].imshow(output_array, cmap='gray')
axs[1].set_title('Output Data')
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
loaded raster-image size:  (5604, 3996)
Unique values in input array: [-999.           1.09         1.0965841 ...   10.15        10.16
   10.18     ]
time taken:  24.95163631439209
```

Output Image:

[image]

You need to set your threshold value properly according to your dem, which will generate more appropriate output. Also, set the patch size according to your memory constraint.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will analize it slowly since there are new things to me. Check out the solution from Simon. It is very simple and fast, since it relies on scikit.

Comment: yeah, using `skimage` is a good solution, but since you said you are using your custom script, I tried to make that script execute faster by utilizing multiple cores and processing patch by patch instead of the whole image to save memory.

Answer (score 0):

You flood fill implementation is not bad.  You could make a little faster by careful optimization (or a lot faster by using a different language)...

But your biggest improvement can be had by combining the flood fills for each point into one:

1. Process the source points in order of decreasing `h`
2. Don't reset the `filled` array after flooding from each point.

This takes advantage of the fact that you don't need to flood a point if it's already been flooded with a greater or equal threshold value.  Each pixel will be processed at most once across all of your source points.